# (cudaBindTexture2D) How to bind a pitched-array from the middle

Tags: cuda, textures, bind, offset

I am trying to bind a pitched array from the middle partly (not from the beginning of the array), like followings.

/*1. allocate*/

```
 cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_texinput, &FloatPitch, cols*sizeof(float), rows);
 cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_output, &FloatPitch, cols*sizeof(float), rows);
```

/*2. set row-length of target region (i.e., dividing rows 10 times)*/

```
 int row_div_times = 10;
 int part_rows = rows / row_div_times;
 int part_offset = part_rows*FloatPitch/sizeof(float);
 dim3 threads(16,16);
 dim3 Part_Blocks((cols + threads.x - 1) / threads.x, (Part_rows + threads.y - 1) / threads.y);
```

/*3. processing divided rows, iteratively*/

```
 for (int i = 0; i < row_div_times; i++)
 {
      size_t offsetsize= i*part_offset;            

      /*computing values of "d_tex_input"*/
      calibration << <Part_Blocks, threads, 0, stream[i] >> >
         (d_texinput + i*part_offset );         

      /*
      //###(QUESTION point!) I want to bind the device memory "d_texinput" to texture "tex_mem" only partly like below.
      cudaBindTexture2D(0, tex_mem, &d_texinput[i*part_offset], channelDesc_flt, cols, Part_rows, FloatPitch); //tentative code a;
      ,,, or something like,,,
      cudaBindTexture2D(&offsetsize, tex_mem, &d_texinput, channelDesc_flt, cols, Part_rows, FloatPitch); //tentative code b;
      */
       


       //final computaion with texture
         final_computationwithtexture << <Part_Blocks, threads, 0, stream[i] >> >
         ( d_output + i*part_offset ); 

       cudaUnbindTexture(tex_mem);

 }
```

Please kindly allow me to ask your instruction, advice how to bind the target region of the device memory array partly by revising above( QUESTION point!)?

I tried to understand first argument of cudaBindTExture2D as "offset". but it is not value. it is address. according to the documentation.
i still could not understand the documentation.
I hope I can understand what that is by knowing adequate inputting way to the cudaBindTexture2D.

Answer (score 1):

The offset parameter is not an input, it is an output. That's why it is a pointer. The function will set the offset in bytes. If you want to bind in the middle of an allocation, you set the devPtr argument (third) appropriately and then the function will give you the offset required for texture accesses.

Here is how to understand this: Textures can only be bound with a certain alignment. Memory allocations are always properly aligned. Therefore it is not an issue in most cases. However, if you provide an arbitrary memory address, CUDA has to round down to the alignment and you have to apply the proper offset later on.

Let's say you bind `&float[66]`, the proper alignment might be `&float[64]`, so CUDA starts its texture at that offset and you have to add an offset of 8 bytes for each access to get the desired result. I'm picking random numbers here, I don't know the alignment requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt instruction with good example. since I read the array at every beginning of pitch, sounds this shift issue wont be problem, but It was very important for me to know this basic behavior. I see, now I know the meaning of  1st argument "offset" and why it was need to be output clearly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @mush_head Yeah, it's probably a good idea to put an ```assert(offset == 0)``` in the code just in case but it should be fine.